# openlightspeed server error "Reached max children process limit"

Tags: php, openlitespeed

I just checked the stderr.log file in my server and noticed that this error get repeated at least every second. but the server is running normally without any problem and it can handle thousands of visitors per day.

```
[1163] Reached max children process limit: 10, extra: 0, current: 10, busy: 10, please increase LSAPI_CHILDREN.
```

should I worry about this error and why did it happen in the first place. and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that message means ,  server is trying to run more than 10 PHP processes at same time , yet you have set limit to 10 , so 11th , 12th and afterwards PHP request will have to wait in queue.

If your server capacity is good enough to handle more PHP , you can raise it

go to webadmin console ,   vhost configuration -> your vhost -> external app  ,in your ext-app , you should see 2 settings like screenshot , change them from 10 to a higher number, like 15 or 20 , don't go too high at once , if you allow it to launch too many PHP , it may overwhelm your server.
[image]

if you don't see it in vhost's external app , then go to server-level external app